# c# How to change the visible property of a label created at runtime

Tags: c#, label, visible, invisible

//Here I create the labels at runtime in one click

```
Label[] labels = new Label[countresult];

for (int i = 1; i < countresult; i++)
{
    labels[i] = new Label();
    labels[i].Font = new Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30);
    labels[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    labels[i].AutoSize = true;
    labels[i].Text = "";

    //Here I try to assign the value visible = true

    labels[i].Visible = true;
    labels[i].TabIndex = i;
}
```

//In a private void of a timer tick I assign the name of label to var  "a" and I do the 3 methods

```
string a = string.Format("labels[{0}]", labelscount);
```

//1st method

```
if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(a))
{
    this.Controls[a].Visible=false;
}
```

//2nd method

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    if (control.Name == a)
    {
        control.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

//3rd method

```
if (this.Controls[a] is Label) this.Controls[a].Visible=false;
labelscount++;
```

Unfortunately none works.

Someone know What's happened?

Comment: labels[i].Visible = false;

Have you tried calling this specifically?

Comment: Did you actually add the labels to a parent control?

Comment: Yes I try that but say The name does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the labels to the owning control. So they will never be displayed. So in your loop you need to add the following as the last line...

```
this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
```

Comment: I use that in the next for but nothing, look:

           for (int i = 0; i < countresult; i++)
                {

                    this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
                   

                    }

Comment: Use an index into the control collection and not a string name. So use a number to get a control from the collection, this.Controls[3], rather than by name.

Comment: You're absolutely right. that was the solution!! @phil-wright thank you so much!!!